# checkbox not staying checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I [asked](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/knockoutjs/checkbox%2420not%2420staying%2420checked/knockoutjs/ZGFVH4DTNhc/5E-uyjQ2p1YJ) this on Google groups, but they don't seem to know.

After I check my checkbox it becomes unchecked again, automatically.
When I add an extender and put a debugger there the checkbox is indeed checked, but then after continuing the checkbox becomes unchecked. Even though the stored value of the observable is true, which I checked with Chrome Inspector. Also when I use Chrome Inspector to change the observable the checkbox does stay checked.

My checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: vergelijk" />
```

The definition of my boolean:

```
vergelijk: ko.observable(true)
```

This is a new checkbox so there can't be any existing code for it. Also it would be very wierd to have jQuery code that finds checkboxes and unchecks them. To my knowledge there is no such code.

Found a click handler on the checkbox container, apparently it catches the click event.
And I have an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MrFoxWork/g3era/) of this in JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/MrFoxWork/g3era/

Comment: What alse are you doing with the observable?

Comment: Can you put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate? It's impossible to answer your question without seeing more code.

Comment: There's something more to the problem, as it demonstrably doesn't happen with just what you've shown: http://jsbin.com/iyAHAvo/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/iyAHAvo/1/edit). This is the classic reason you should always create a [minimal, replicating test case](http://sscce.org). 99% of the time, in the process of doing that, you'll find the answer. The other 1% of the time, you have something nice and contained you can put in your question (and also provide a link to on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net -- but beware jsFiddle's odd default of putting your scripts in an `onload` handler).

Comment: Sure except I've made checkboxes before, with knockout data bindings. And until now they always worked. There's nothing exciting about this checkbox, other than that it does not work. JSFiddle doing what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/

Comment: the fiddle you provided has nothing to do with what you ask. maybe wrong copy pasta?

Comment: The yes-no is displayed to test the value stored internally. To check that it corrosponds with whether the box is checked or not. In my case they don't corrospond, so the checkbox is unchecked, while the underlying value is true.

Comment: check the fiddle you link on your previous comment! all I see are two inputs and no checkboxes.

Comment: Posted a fiddle of what you want isn't as helpful as a fiddle of what you have. Nothing is wrong with the code you original posted, so something else is going on, but nobody can guess at that without *seeing you code*. As TJ said, you need a small, self-contained example of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, my changes where not saved, I just edited someone elses example. If I could reproduce the problem I'd probably know the cause... Was hoping someone else ran into the same thing. I'll try to remake the JSfiddle and post it again.

Comment: Finally found the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/MrFoxWork/g3era/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click binding handler din't return anything, apparently that causes the checkbox to remain unchecked. To get the action working, the binding handler has to return true.